# Mixed OR AND taxonomy query

Tags: wordpress

I have created a WP Query argument list like so hoping it will select all posts with term 2 and then from results all others with relation OR.

```
$similar_properties_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'post__not_in' => array(get_post_ID() ),
    'post_parent__not_in' => array(get_post_ID() ),   
    
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'language',
            'terms' => '2'
        ),
        array (
        'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                 array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'property-feature',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array(1954,1958,1966,1970,1972)
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'property-city',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array(145)
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'property-status',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array(38)
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'property-type',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array(21)
                    )
                
                )
            )       
    )
);
```

The actual WP mysql query created is as as below:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  agn_posts.ID FROM agn_posts  LEFT JOIN agn_term_relationships ON (agn_posts.ID = agn_term_relationships.object_id)  LEFT JOIN agn_term_relationships AS tt1 ON (agn_posts.ID = tt1.object_id)  LEFT JOIN agn_term_relationships AS tt2 ON (agn_posts.ID = tt2.object_id)  LEFT JOIN agn_term_relationships AS tt3 ON (agn_posts.ID = tt3.object_id)  LEFT JOIN agn_term_relationships AS tt4 ON (agn_posts.ID = tt4.object_id) WHERE 1=1  AND agn_posts.ID NOT IN (1440) AND agn_posts.post_parent NOT IN (1440) AND ( 
  agn_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2) 
  AND 
  ( 
    ( 
      tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (1954,1958,1966,1970,1972) 
      AND 
      tt2.term_taxonomy_id IN (145) 
      AND 
      tt3.term_taxonomy_id IN (38) 
      AND 
      tt4.term_taxonomy_id IN (21)
    )
  )
) AND agn_posts.post_type = 'property' AND (agn_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR agn_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY agn_posts.ID ORDER BY agn_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

...and it is not giving me the results as I would  need to get.

If I change the tt1 term relationship to OR, then the result is fine.

```
 tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (1954,1958,1966,1970,1972) 
          OR  //from AND to OR
          tt2.term_taxonomy_id IN (145) 
          OR //from AND to OR
          tt3.term_taxonomy_id IN (38) 
          OR //from AND to OR
          tt4.term_taxonomy_id IN (21)
```

The problem Is, from my naked eye, the argument list above is valid for creating the query I am looking for, but somehow something is missing. May be you can see, where is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't nest the four arrays/clauses in an array:

```php
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND', // for clauses 1 and 2
    array( // clause 1
        'taxonomy' => 'language',
        'terms'    => '2',
    ),
    array( // clause 2
        'relation' => 'OR', // for sub-clause 1..

        // you shouldn't nest the sub-sub-clauses
        array( // sub-clause 1
            array( // sub-sub-clause 1
                'taxonomy' => 'property-feature',
                ...
            ),
            array( // sub-sub-clause 2
                'taxonomy' => 'property-city',
                ...
            ),
            array( // sub-sub-clause 3
                'taxonomy' => 'property-status',
                ...
            ),
            array( // sub-sub-clause 4
                'taxonomy' => 'property-type',
                ...
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Instead, make the arrays same level as the `relation`:

```php
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND', // for clauses 1 and 2
    array( // clause 1
        'taxonomy' => 'language',
        'terms'    => '2',
    ),
    array( // clause 2
        'relation' => 'OR', // for the sub-clauses 1, 2, 3 and 4

        // instead of nesting, do like so:
        array( // sub-clause 1
            'taxonomy' => 'property-feature',
            'terms'    => array( 1954, 1958, 1966, 1970, 1972 ),
        ),
        array( // sub-clause 2
            'taxonomy' => 'property-city',
            'terms'    => array( 145 ),
        ),
        array( // sub-clause 3
            'taxonomy' => 'property-status',
            'terms'    => array( 38 ),
        ),
        array( // sub-clause 4
            'taxonomy' => 'property-type',
            'terms'    => array( 21 ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

And that one would give you this SQL command as part of the `WHERE`:

```sql
agn_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2) # language
  AND 
  ( 
    tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (1954,1958,1966,1970,1972) # feature
    OR 
    tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (145) # city
    OR 
    tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (38)  # status
    OR 
    tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (21)  # type
  )
```

And BTW, `'field' => 'id'` should be `'field' => 'term_id'`, but the default field is indeed `term_id`, so you may omit the `field` arg. Also, WordPress does not have a function named `get_post_ID`, so I think you meant to use `get_the_ID()`? :)